# Порядок сортировки при инсерте с сортированной  таблицы

Tags: sql-server, sql

Гарантированно ли точное соответсвие сортировки строк при инсерте с уже сортированной таблицы? Гарантированно ли два селекта вернут тот же порядок?

```
      declare @OUTPUT table 
        ( 
           [row1]        int, 
           [row2]      varchar(255), 
           [row3]       int 
        )

INSERT INTO @OUTPUT
SELECT TOP 1000
[row1]
      ,[row2]
      ,[row3]
  FROM table
  ORDER BY [row1]

  select * from @OUTPUT
  select * from @OUTPUT
```

Comment: @SomeName, конечно нет, поскольку реляционная модель, на которой основан SQL ничего не говорит о порядке кортежей.

Даже в новой версии той же СУБД (или при другой физической организации таблиц и т.д.) результаты могут отличаться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Но это весьма вероятно, особенно при наличии кластерного индекса. Если нужна сортировка - используйте order by.